# Python: Building a tuple consisting of min values from list of tuples

Tags: python

I'm absolutely sure this question must have been asked multiple times before, but for the life of me i couldn't find a thread answering this question:

I am making a model exporter where i want to calculate the minimum and maximum bounds of each object, by going through a list of vertices and picking the lowest and highest x, y, and z values into their own min/max tuple on the same form. The way i do this right now is like this:

```
x = max(vertices,key=itemgetter(0))[0]
y = max(vertices,key=itemgetter(1))[1]
z = max(vertices,key=itemgetter(2))[2]
extents_max = (x, y, z)
x = min(vertices,key=itemgetter(0))[0]
y = min(vertices,key=itemgetter(1))[1]
z = min(vertices,key=itemgetter(2))[2]
extents_min = (x, y, z)
```

And this works, but is there a more elegant, one-liner way of doing this in python?

Comment: Can you give a simple, reproducible example of what `vertices` might look like?

Comment: Also why are you taking the first and second elements of lists for `y` and `z` respectively?

Comment: [maps](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#map) seems to be the thing you strive for but, just give us `vertices` and a bit more of the code

Comment: "vertices" is a list of tuples on the form (x, y, z). I use max() / min() to sort the tuples by item 0 (x), 1 (y), and 2 (z), then i retrieve the item i sorted by for each axis and use them to build a new tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove your repeated 0, 1, 2, it's a one-liner:

```
extents_max = [max(vertices,key=itemgetter(i))[i] for i in range(3)]
```

If you need it to remain a tuple as you have shown in your example:

```
extents_max = tuple(max(vertices,key=itemgetter(i))[i] for i in range(3))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Not as compact as Willem's answer, but more readable in my opinion, hence marked as answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate these with sequence unpacking:

```
mins, maxs = zip(*[(min(map(itemgetter(i), vertices)),
                    max(map(itemgetter(i), vertices)))
                   for i in range(3)])
```

For example:

```
>>> vertices = [(1,4,2), (1,3,0), (4,2,5)]
>>> mins, maxs = zip(*[(min(map(itemgetter(i), vertices)),
...                     max(map(itemgetter(i), vertices)))
...                    for i in range(3)])
>>> mins
(1, 2, 0)
>>> maxs
(4, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Demodata:

```
verts =  [(-94, -24, -87), (90, 27, -56), (-22, -59, -44), (50, -70, 52),
          (-31, 37, -24), (-73, 53, 66), (-47, -28, 99), (-3, -42, -66), 
          (2, 85, 58), (79, -86, 39)]
```

Find min/max:

```
z = [(min(l),max(l)) for l in zip(*verts)]  # [(min,max) for each 
                                                  #  (x0,..,xn),(y0,..,yn),(z0,..,zn) ]

extends_min, extends_max = zip(*z)

print(extends_min, extends_max)
```

Output:

```
(-94, -86, -87) (90, 85, 99)
```

Comment: unfortunately thats about the same as @WillemVanOnsem does - and he gots it in a one liner :/